# notion of connection on Torsors

Tags: connections, ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi,
   Can anyone please enlighten me on the notion of connection for G-torsors?

**Edit (by WW)** *For some reason the OP decides to add clarification below as an answer rather than editing the question. I'm copying the clarification he/she provided:*

I have a smooth complex projective curve $X$ and $G$ is semisimple, simply connected complex algebraic group. The paper I was trying to read associates a group $G$ scheme over $X$, they call it Bruhat-tits group scheme. I want to know if we have any notion of connection on $G$ torsors on $X$?

Comment: Do you want a definition, or do you want some kind of enlightening discussion?  It would help if you provided more context in your question.  You can do this by clicking the "edit" button under the question, and typing the relevant information into the text box.

Comment: Dear Willie, In algebraic geometry people of often use "$G$-torsor" to mean "principal $G$-bundle" over an arbitrary base (not just over a point).  This is the context in which the question is asked.

Comment: Dear Emerton: I stand corrected over my ignorance of the terminology. It would've helped if the OP were to have specified the context and tagged appropriately. (Willie shuffles off to fix the mistaken tag he introduced.)

Answer (score 2):

Grothendieck has the following interpretation: A connection on a family is the datum that glues fibers over first order neighborhoods.  When you have a $G$-torsor over $X$, a connection will allow you to identify the fibers of the torsor when you move along a tangent vector.

Here is a universal definition: Let $I$ be the ideal sheaf of the diagonal $\Delta: X \hookrightarrow X \times X$, and let $X^{(2)}$ be the subscheme of $X \times X$ cut out by $I^2$.  This is the first order neighborhood of the diagonal.  Composition with the canonical projection maps yields $p_1, p_2: X^{(2)} \to X \times X \to X$.  By pulling back our $G$-torsor $P \to X$, along these maps, we get two $G$-torsors on $X^{(2)}$.  A connection on $\pi$ is an isomorphism $\eta: p_1^* P \to p_2^* P$.  The connection is flat (or integrable) if $p_{13}^* \eta = p_{23}^*\eta \circ p_{12}^*\eta$, where the $p_{ij}$ come from the first order neighborhood of the diagonal in $X^3$, together with projections $X \times X \times X \to X \times X$.

There is also a functorial definition for flat connection using the formalism of crystals.  See, e.g., the notes from Nov. 17 and 19 on [this page](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/).